# Elastic search AccessDeniedException[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] -- Access denied error

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, elastic-stack

I am trying to use nfs mount as my elasticsearch data directory, earlier I was using host storage.
But when I am trying to up my container, I am facing below mentioned error :

```
 ElasticsearchException[failed to bind service]; nested: AccessDeniedException[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0];
es02    | Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0
es02    |   at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
es02    |   at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
es02    |   at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
es02    |   at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:388)
es02    |   at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:694)
es02    |   at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:801)
es02    |   at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:787)
es02    |   at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.lambda$new$0(NodeEnvironment.java:275)
es02    |   at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment$NodeLock.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:212)
es02    |   at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:272)
es02    |   at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:362)
es02    |   at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:289)
```

I am using docker-compose for the same earlier my cluster was working fine,when i was using host storage but when i tried to switch to NFS storage i am facing above mentioned error.
Below is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
volumes:
  data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
       type: nfs
       device: ":/data1/elasticsearch_data"
       o: addr=10.10.15.46,rw
#volumes:
#  repo:
#    driver: local
#    driver_opts:
#       type: none
#       device: /apm_backup
#       o: bind
#
services:
  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.0
    container_name: es02
    volumes:
      - data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
#      - ./unicast_hosts.txt:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/unicast_hosts.txt
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - node.master=true
      - node.data=true
      - cluster.name=apm-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01
#      - discovery.seed_providers=file
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms10g -Xmx10g"
      - XPACK_SECURITY_ENABLED=false
#      - path.repo=/apm_backup
#    command: ["elasticsearch", "-Elogger.level=DEBUG"]
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    restart: "unless-stopped"
    logging:
      driver: 'json-file'
      options:
          max-size: '2m'
          max-file: '5'
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    extra_hosts:
      - "es01:10.10.26.27"
      - "es02:10.10.26.111"
      - "es03:10.10.26.111"
    network_mode: "host"
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "APM-monitoring"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--write-out", "'HTTP %{http_code}'", "--silent", "--output", "/dev/null", "http://es02:9200/"]
      retries: 10
      interval: 10s
```

[This is my directory permission and location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jD5Q.png)

What I have tried till now:

chown 1000:1000 elasticsearch_data (1000 uid of vimzy user mentioned in photo).

I have tried *priviliged=true* in docker-compose.
and apart from this tried multiple ways to counter permission denied issue.

Any help...

Answer (score 24):

This error is occurring due to permission issue on specified path.

Change the path from `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data` to `/var/lib/elasticsearch/data`

It will work!

Comment: what is the permission issue that you mentioned?

Comment: For elastic version 7 use the /var/lib/elasticsearch/data. For elastic version 8 is /usr/share/elasticsearch/data

Comment: will start, but won't do what's intended. Will not write data over the mounted volume, instead will write to internal container path "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data", which is the correct path even for v7.

Answer (score 9):

this fixed the problem for me

```
sudo chown -R 1000:root docker_data
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens due to bind mount. For example if your docker compose file is something similar as below

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:8.9.2
    volumes:
      - ./esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
volumes:
  esdata:
```

It will throw permission error as the `esdata` doesn't have the correct permission that allows elasticsearch running inside the container to write/read

To solve this you need to run this command

```bash
sudo chown -R 1000:root esdata
```

Explanation:
Every user in linux is associated with an id

```bash
#This will give the id of the current user, in most cases it will be 1000
id -u
```

Inside the container the user is `elastic` is having id as `1000`

Therefore we need to give the permissions to the user having id `1000` to read/write data directory in the bind mount, in this case the directory is `esdata`. Therefore the command `sudo chown -R 1000:root esdata` has 1000

Answer (score 0):

It might be an incompatibility with NFSv3, try to switch to NFSv4 as detailed in this blog:

https://www.frakkingsweet.com/elasticsearch-nfs-and-locking-issues/

Comment: `
       o: "addr=10.10.15.46,vers=4,rw"
`       Hi added this as well but no changes same error as mentioned above @RIcardo

Comment: I think you have to enable v4 in the NFS server as well. Remember that updating the volume options and redeploying the stack does not modify an already existing volume. Volumes also don't get removed from the docker swarm nodes when they are no longer in use. You need to go to each individual node and manually delete the volumes using docker volume rm <VOLUME_NAME>.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I am using docker-compose  down -v to remove volumes orphanges volumes,containers . And V4 is already enable on NFS server

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me:

I formatted my NFS Disk and then mounted the nfs disk as a device in docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
volumes:
  data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
       type: nfs
       device: ":/data1/elasticsearch_data"
       o: addr=10.10.15.46,rw
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).